# .htacces RewriteRule redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file that redirects to the correct php file:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ read.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

For example `mysite.com/post/100` redirects to `mysite.com/post/read.php`  and I can use 100 in my PHP file as a identifier.

This all works well, until I use `mysite.com/post/100/` or `mysite.com/post/100/abc`. The file is still being redirected, but all of my css files and includes() do not work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/site.css" type="text/css">
```

This server is going one map up, so the include doesn't work anymore.

Any solution for this? The use of http://www.mysite.com/styles/site.css is not a solution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an absolute path like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/site.css" type="text/css">
```